# Solver libraries fail to load on linux

Tags: alloy

Alloy fails to load dynamic libraries of the included solvers from the jar file.

I installed alloy from AUR on 64 bit Linux. The jar file does contain e.g.

```
99085 Sun Feb 22 19:21:37 AST 2015 amd64-linux/libglucose.so
```

However, when I launch alloy, I get messages:

```
Failed to load: libglucose.so
```

How do I get alloy to find these libraries?

Comment: I think this is better as an issue on Github.com/AlloyTools/org.alloytools.alloy repo

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Because it is not a good question for Stackoverflow. I'd hoped you deleted it and added the bug to the AlloyTools site.

Comment: The question is legit and answers might help others encountering the same problem, so here, have an upvote ;-)

Comment: I did add the bug to the issues on github. However, I suspect/hope that the solution will be helpful to others who encounter similar problems. I did try several workarounds, e.g. unpacking the jar renaming the subdirectory amd64-linux to x86_64-linux and then repacking the jar. This did not solve the problem, but I still hope a similarly simple workaround might help. Even if the solution requires a change to the source code, an explanation why this became a problem and how to solve it will benefit other.